# Why the intersection appears in the matrix

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, matrix-calculus

Its for a calculus homework. They give me 2 subspace basis and a matrix, and after row reduction it appears the sum and the intersection. I have to explain why and how appears the intersection. This is the [homework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uxWA.jpg).

$ basis-S = {(1,2,1,1,1),(1,0,1,0,1),(-1,1,0,1,1)} $ 
$ basis-W = {(1,1,1,2,-2),(1,3,1,3,-2)} $

So, in the matrix we have:

- Green -> basis-S
- Yellow -> basis-S
- Orange -> basis-W
- Purple -> null, 0

After the row reduction, we have:

- Sum -> $ (1,2,1,1,1)(0,1,0,2,-3)(0,0,-1,4,-11)(0,0,0,3,-6) $ (upper left)
- Intersection -> $ (0,2,0,1,0) $ (bottom right)

So i have to explain why appears the intersection in the right. How the information of basis-W pass to the right and appears the intersection.

If you can help me, i appreciate it. Any question, tell me. Thanks!

Comment: btw I haven't seen the word "scalation" before; the terms I've seen are "row reduction" or "Gaussian elimination". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Comment: Could you give some indication which linear algebra topics you have seen? Do you know what is meant by the projection $\pi_1:V\oplus V\to V$ on the first factor?

Comment: @stewbasic sorry, english its not my first language, row reduction is what i mean. And what i have been like this V⊕V, is direct sum of subspace, i dont remember seeing projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use $B_S$ and $B_W$ to denote the matrices containing the given bases, so the initial matrix can be written in block form as
$$
  \begin{bmatrix}B_S&B_S\\B_W&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Hint: An element of the row space of the original matrix is of the form
$$
  \begin{bmatrix}a&b\end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}B_S&B_S\\B_W&0\end{bmatrix}
  =\begin{bmatrix}aB_S+bB_W&aB_S\end{bmatrix}
$$
If the first half of this vector is zero, what does it tell you? Now recall that the row reduced matrix has the same row space as the original matrix.